# How to ignore "ACL packet for unknown connection handle" logs (or fix it)?

Tags: arch-linux, logs, bluetooth

My Bluetooth devices are working perfectly and I can even connect and use several devices at the same time (keyboard, mouse, speaker, headset...).

But whenever I use them (e.g. typing or moving the mouse) these logs keep flooding my kernel log.

> Bluetooth: hci0: ACL packet for unknown connection handle 3804

How can I fix these, if it is an issue, or at least ignore the logs so they don't appear anymore?

### System details

```
 uname -a
Linux paulodiovani-thinkpad 6.1.25-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr 20 13:48:36 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 bluetoothctl show D8:80:83:EC:A9:84
Controller D8:80:83:EC:A9:84 (public)
    Name: paulodiovani-thinkpad
    Alias: paulodiovani-thinkpad
    Class: 0x006c010c
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: no
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
    Pairable: no
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0542
    Discovering: no
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
    SupportedInstances: 0x10 (16)
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: 1M
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: 2M
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: Coded

 lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc QCNFA765 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```